# Windows service bus with Tridion RemoteSynchronization

Tags: 2011, deployer, cache-channel-service

We are trying to connect  windows service bus with tridion deployer to send the cache invalidation messages from where the external applications will read(get) the messages.

I know there is a blog which talks about configuring tridion with [activeMQ](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/usingsdltridionobjectcachingwithapacheactivemq.aspx)

I have tried using the below values in storage config

```
<RemoteSynchronization>
                <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Topic="Servicebus Topic"> 
                <JndiContext>
                <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory"/>
                <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="amqps://owner:SharedAccessKey@machine name:9355/namespace"/>
                <Property Name="topic.Tridion" Value="Servicebus Topic"/>
                </JndiContext>
                </Connector>
            </RemoteSynchronization>
```

I have added the required jars mentioned in the msdn as well.

But when do publish i am getting the below error.

```
30:27,629 ERROR CacheChannel - Could not connect to Cache Channel Service on startup, will attempt again in 60000ms
com.tridion.cache.CacheException: Unable to initialize JMS CacheChannelConnector, Unable to load property file:amqps://owner:SharedAccessKey@machine name:9355/namespace., Unable to load property file:amqps://owner:SharedAccessKey@machine name:9355/namespace.
    at com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector.validate(JMSCacheChannelConnector.java:184) ~[cd_cache.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.init(CacheChannel.java:303) [cd_cache.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.configure(CacheChannel.java:271) [cd_cache.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.createCacheChannel(CacheChannel.java:230) [cd_cache.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.cache.CacheFactory.configure(CacheFactory.java:222) [cd_cache.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.CacheConfigurationLoader.configure(CacheConfigurationLoader.java:17) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) [cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:138) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:107) [cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:105) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:85) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:57) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:58) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:90) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:145) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:74) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:185) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:96) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:60) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:81) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:181) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
```

Any thoughts or inputs will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: I can move forward  by giving the java.naming.provider.url property value to point to properties file with the required value like

java.naming.factory.initial =org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory

connectionfactory.ServiceBusConnectionFactory = amqp://user:password@rsvcbus01.xxx.yyyyyyy.com:7666/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace

now i am getting the below error 

om.tridion.cache.CacheException: Unable to initialize JMS CacheChannelConnector, TopicName, Topic Name...
 at com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector.validate(JMSCacheChannelConnector.java:184) ~[cd_cache.jar:na]

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be asking is whether the Tridion Cache Channel Service works with the Window Service Bus instead of a JMS Provider.  The answer here is no.  A Java Messaging Service, as per the JSR-914 spec, is required if you want to configure Tridion's Cache Channel via a service bus.  Otherwise your option is to use the standard Tridion Windows Service (assuming you're on Windows) which communicates via RMI.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My Question is actually to replace the Tridion's cache Channel service with Windows service Bus.
Basically configuring windows service bus instead of Tridion cache channel service in the RemoteSynchronization section of storage.conf